# memory keep arising with openai embedding in Flask

Tags: flask, openai-api, embedding

here is my Python code which uses Flask as web framework, the api simply test the usage of OpenAI embedding. with each API call, the memory of this PID(thread of the code) keeps arising. So what is  the solution to solve this problem? Anyone has some idea?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request
from openai import OpenAI

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    texts = request.json["texts"]
    no = request.json["no"]
    client = OpenAI()
    response = client.embeddings.create(
        input=texts,
        model="text-embedding-ada-002",
        encoding_format="float"
    )
    print(response.usage)

    return "ok"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

the solution of my problem

Comment: Shouldn't the `OpenAI` instance be treated like a database link and session? I mean created once per application worker not once per request as in your code.

Comment: And for the context, on which operating system do you experience this?

Comment: actually, it's the same situation when I initialize the client outside the api, the memory also keeps arising with each api call.